# Grouping different arrays based on it's key

Tags: javascript

I have arrays like this,

```
   0: {"pure_id":"1","branch_id":"45"}
   1: {"pure_id":"2","branch_id":"45"}
   2:  {"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"45"}
   3:  {"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"45"}
```

I am looking to group the above arrays into a single array based on pure_id, so the result array will be this below, and the index will be pure_id index

```
  1: [{"pure_id":"1","branch_id":"45"}]
  2: [{"pure_id":"2","branch_id":"45"}]
  3: [{"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"45"},{"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"45"}]
```

I am trying lots of things honestly, but I cannot make it work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const result = [];

 for(const el of array) 
  (result[el.pure_id] || (result[el.pure_id] = [])).push(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the *new* object literal rest and spread syntax, the property expression syntax, and `.reduce()` makes this pretty short and simple.

```js
var arr = [
 {"pure_id":"1","branch_id":"45"},
 {"pure_id":"2","branch_id":"45"},
 {"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"45"},
 {"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"45"}
];

var result = arr.reduce((res, {pure_id, ...props}) =>
  ({...res, [pure_id]: (res[pure_id] || []).concat({pure_id, ...props})})
, {});

console.log(result);
```

The `.reduce()` is of course just creating a new object. Each iteration takes the accumulated properties and adds them to an object literal, but with the `pure_id` being the concatenation of the properties of the current object (copy) to an array.

Answer (score 0):

If don't use reduce, the codes will be like below:

Assuming your expected result is one array like:
`[[{'pure_id':0, 'branch_id':1}], [{'pure_id':1, 'branch_id':2}]]`

```js
//assuming your array is like below:
var test = [{"pure_id":"1","branch_id":"43"},
   {"pure_id":"2","branch_id":"44"},
   {"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"45"},
   {"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"46"}]

var result = []
var index_db = {} //use dict to save the mapping between the index of result and pure_id
var index = 0
test.forEach(function(item){
  if(item.pure_id in index_db){
    result[index_db[item.pure_id]].push(item)
  }
  else{
    result.push([item])
    index_db[item.pure_id] = index++
  }
});
console.log(result)
```

Below is one reduce version:

```js
//assuming your array is like below:
var test = [{"pure_id":"1","branch_id":"43"},
   {"pure_id":"2","branch_id":"44"},
   {"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"45"},
   {"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"46"}]

result = test.reduce(function(pre, cur){
  if(cur['pure_id'] in pre['indexes']){
    pre['result'][pre['indexes'][cur['pure_id']]].push(cur)
  }
  else{
    pre['result'].push([cur])
    pre['indexes'][cur['pure_id']] = pre['pos']++
  }
  return pre
}, {'pos':0, 'indexes':{}, 'result':[]})
console.log(result['result'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I often see people struggle with something in programming that outside of it would not be a problem. Instead of arrays and objects, you can think of it as fruit.

Imagine a bucket of fruit. You want to sort the one bucket of fruit into 1 bucket for each color of fruit (color just being a property of a piece of fruit). So you would:

1. grab one fruit at a time
2. figure out it's color
3. if there is no bucket for that color, get one
4. put the fruit in the proper bucket
5. repeat until there are no fruits left

What we created was an algorithm for sorting fruit by color. The problem you are solving is very similar. In pseudocode it would be:

```
for each fruit
  color = fruit.color
  if not bucket[color]
    make bucket[color]
  put fruit in bucket[color]
```

to translate that to JS

```
var fruits = [
 {color: "red"},
 {color: "orange"},
 {color: "pink"},
 {color: "red"}
];

var buckets = {};

for (var i=0; i<fruits.length; i++) {
  var fruit = fruits[i];
  var color = fruit.color;
  if (!buckets[color])
    buckets[color] = [];
  buckets[color].push(fruit);
}
```

So now, if you want to work with your array, the algorithm stays the same you just swap out the parts.

```js
var things = [
 {"pure_id":"1","branch_id":"45"},
 {"pure_id":"2","branch_id":"45"},
 {"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"45"},
 {"pure_id":"3","branch_id":"45"}
];

var grouped = [];
for (let i=0; i<things.length; i++) {
  var thing = things[i];
  var id = thing['pure_id'];
  if (!grouped[id])
    grouped[id] = [];
  grouped[id].push(thing);
}
console.log(grouped)
```

So, here we are at the first solution. It works! There are better solutions (using reduce, forEach or others) but don't let data structures like arrays or dictionaries scare you away. Think about it in simpler terms if it helps.